# How to store SQL query result into variable to include in a later SELECT statement

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, select

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT MAX(a.date), d.group, c.name, b.name_id 
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN table3 c ON b.name_id = c.name_id
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON b.group_id = d.group_id
WHERE a.foo = '12345'
GROUP BY d.group, c.name, b.name_id
ORDER BY MAX(a.date)
```

It returns something like this:

| date | group | name | name_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 | FOOFOO | FA FA | 1 |
| yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 | FOOFOO | FA FA | 2 |
| yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 | FOOFOO | FA FA | 3 |
| yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 | FOOFOO | FA FA | 4 |
| yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 | FOOFOO | FA FA | 5 |

Focusing on `name_id`, I want to take **all of them** (about 800) and store them into an array-like variable. Then utilize said array-like variable in the following type of clause in separate SELECT statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id) 
FROM table999 a
WHERE a.foofoo IN @array
```

I've seen that you can build temporary tables that act as arrays, but I'm not sure if that's exactly what I'm looking for. I've also read that you can utilize variables (via `@var`) but it seems those can only hold one piece of data. Can what I'm looking for be done in SQL? Is there an array-like variable where I can push these `name_id`'s to? Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: temporary tables or table vars

Comment: More likely, if I am honest, a `JOIN` or `EXISTS` could be more performant. Especially when you don't need all those `JOIN`s from the original query to do that.

Comment: `JOIN` will not work for this example. Already tried it and I received an incorrect count. The other `JOIN`'s are necessary in this example. Regarding `EXISTS` how would I specify what `name_id`'s I want in the subquery? If it's just use a `WHERE` clause with an `IN` statement, then I'd rather avoid all that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using an `EXISTS` here. You can also simplify your initial query as a result. You don't need `table3` and `table4` as these don't filter the data, and so would only slow the query down.

You just an `INNER JOIN` between tables `table1` and `table2`. This can be changed to an `INNER JOIN` as you *want* `t2.name_id` to have a non-`NULL` value, which means that the `JOIN` must be true (though I do assume that `name_id` itself isn't `NULL`able).

This gives you the following query instead:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(a.id)
FROM dbo.table999 t999
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM dbo.table2 t2
                  JOIN dbo.table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
             WHERE t1.foo = '12345'
               AND t2.name_id = t999.foofoo);
```

There's little need to a table variable here (what you call an "array", which SQL Server doesn't have), as this would just be an additional cost to run the first query (with all its additional `JOIN`s),  *store* that data somewhere (which *might* be in RAM, but could be in a table in `tempdb`), and then *read* that data back.

Comment: What is `t999.foofoo` refer to? I understand that t999 refers to table 999 but what is `.foofoo` referring to?

Comment: The column `foofoo`, @Crimp . That's the name *you* used, so it's the name I used.

Comment: Lol. Just now saw that. My apologies

Answer (score 2):

use a table variable, it's different from a temporary table because it only exists in memory for the length of the batch. Note: this is only good for SQL Server.

````
declare @mytablevar TABLE (name_id int);


INSERT INTO @mytablevar
SELECT b.name_id FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN table3 c ON b.name_id = c.name_id
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON b.group_id = d.group_id
WHERE a.foo = '12345'
GROUP BY d.group, c.name, b.name_id
ORDER BY MAX(a.date);


SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM table999
WHERE a.foofoo IN (SELECT name_id FROM @mytablevar);

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression and a subquery in your IN clause.

```
WITH tempTable(foofoo) AS (select foofoo from firsttable)  
SELECT COUNT(table999.id) FROM table999
WHERE table999.foofoo IN (select foofoo from tempTable)
```

Comment: This looks like it is likely a valid approach but it is not a temporary table. This is using a common table expression (cte).

Comment: you are correct.